SecretsManager mock in jest testing
i am trying to create unit test for my lambda function but keeping getting the error that Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret when calling the getSecretValue method
import { SecretsManager } from '@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager';
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEvent
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  console.log('Event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  
  try {
    // Get DB credentials from Secrets Manager
    console.log('Getting DB credentials...');
    const secretsManager = new SecretsManager();
    const secretArn = process.env.DB_SECRET_ARN!;
    
    console.log('Fetching secret:', secretArn);
    const secretResponse = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({
      SecretId: secretArn
    });
    
    if (!secretResponse.SecretString) {
      throw new Error('Database credentials not found');
    }
    
    const credentials = JSON.parse(secretResponse.SecretString);
    console.log('Got credentials successfully');

    // Initialize DB pool
    console.log('Initializing DB pool...');
    const pool = new Pool({
      user: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT || '5432'),
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    });

    // Handle different HTTP methods
    switch (event.httpMethod) {
      case 'GET':
        console.log('Executing GET query...');
        const result = await pool.query('SELECT NOW()');
        await pool.end();
        
        return {
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'Database connection successful',
            timestamp: result.rows[0].now
          })
        };

      case 'POST':
        const body = JSON.parse(event.body || '{}');
        await pool.end();
        
        return {
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'POST request successful',
            body: body
          })
        };

      default:
        return {
          statusCode: 405,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'Method not allowed'
          })
        };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error details:', {
      message: error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error',
      stack: error instanceof Error ? error.stack : undefined,
      name: error instanceof Error ? error.name : 'Unknown',
      env: {
        DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST,
        DB_PORT: process.env.DB_PORT,
        DB_NAME: process.env.DB_NAME,
        HAS_SECRET_ARN: !!process.env.DB_SECRET_ARN
      }
    });

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Internal server error',
        error: error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error'
      })
    };
  }
};

I try to mock the getsecretvalue function as shown below
import { SecretsManager, GetSecretValueCommandOutput } from '@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager';
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent } from 'aws-lambda';
import { handler } from '../lambda/handler';

const mockSecretData: GetSecretValueCommandOutput = {
  ARN: 'test-secret-arn',
  Name: 'test_creds',
  VersionId: 'x',
  SecretString: '{"username":"test","password":"password"}',
  VersionStages: ['x'],
  CreatedDate: new Date(),
  $metadata: {}
};

// Mock modules
jest.mock('pg', () => ({
  Pool: jest.fn()
}));

// Mock SecretsManager with correct error handling
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager', () => {
  return {
    SecretsManager: jest.fn(() => ({
      getSecretValue: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockSecretData)
  })
  )};
});

describe('lambda test', () => {
  let mockPool: jest.Mocked<{
    query: jest.Mock;
    end: jest.Mock;
  }>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    mockPool = {
      query: jest.fn(),
      end: jest.fn()
    };

    (Pool as unknown as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => mockPool);

    // Set environment variables
    process.env.DB_SECRET_ARN = 'test-secret-arn';
    process.env.DB_HOST = 'test-host';
    process.env.DB_PORT = '5432';
    process.env.DB_NAME = 'test-db';
  });

  describe('GET requests', () => {
    it('should handle successful GET request', async () => {
      const mockTimestamp = new Date().toISOString();
      
      // Mock successful query response
      mockPool.query.mockResolvedValueOnce({
        rows: [{ now: mockTimestamp }],
        rowCount: 1,
        command: 'SELECT',
        oid: null,
        fields: []
      });
      mockPool.end.mockResolvedValueOnce(undefined);

      const event: APIGatewayProxyEvent = {
        httpMethod: 'GET',
        body: null,
        headers: {},
        isBase64Encoded: false,
        multiValueHeaders: {},
        multiValueQueryStringParameters: null,
        path: '/',
        pathParameters: null,
        queryStringParameters: null,
        requestContext: {} as any,
        resource: '',
        stageVariables: null
      };

      const response = await handler(event);

      // Verify response
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).toEqual({
        message: 'Database connection successful',
        timestamp: mockTimestamp
      });
      expect(mockPool.query).toHaveBeenCalledWith('SELECT NOW()');
      expect(mockPool.end).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
});

I expect that the mock function would return the mockSecretData with the SecretsString that i can use. Does anyone experience something similar to this, what did you guys used to unit test a lambda function that need to mock a class?

If youre ok by using a library, I can recommend this one: https://github.com/m-radzikowski/aws-sdk-client-mock.  There is also an AWS Blogpost on how to use it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/mocking-modular-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3-in-unit-tests/
